# Apache Camel using Spring DSL

Tags: apache-camel

How can properties files be used with Apache Camel to refer to configurable properties For example, if there's a route that reads files from a folder, how can that folder location be configured in a properties file. Using Spring DSL

Answer (score 1):

Please refer to this [link](http://camel.apache.org/how-do-i-use-spring-property-placeholder-with-camel-xml.html)

You can configure properties file, the standard way in spring using

```
context:property-placeholder
```

Then use the properties with $ notation. Just refer the caveat in above link. You'll need to create an endpoint using the property and then use that in your route.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Camel's Properties component](http://camel.apache.org/properties.html) for this.

First, add a line like this to your Spring XML, to initialise the Properties component bean:

```
<bean id="properties" class="org.apache.camel.component.properties.PropertiesComponent"
    <property name="location" value="classpath:application.properties"/>
</bean>
```

Then create a file in your classpath (e.g. `src/main/resources/application.properties`) containing your properties, like this:

```
your.directory.name=home
another.value=foo
```

Then to reference these properties in a Camel route, just use the property name, surrounded by twin braces, e.g.:

```
<from uri="file:src/{{your.directory.name}}?noop=true"/>
<to ... />
```